# libxml2: reading XML via http-Ressources fails

Tags: c, libxml2

I just try to read/parse xml-Files using libxml2 via MS Visual Studio.
Installation was succesful so far.

First try is read an online http-xml via xmlReadFile() in a simple c console app.

Reading it at its original source fails, while reading a local copy works fine.

See full code below.

Using the local saved xml-file via

```
doc = xmlReadFile(loc, NULL, 0);
```

gives the correct result "current observation".

But if I try to get the online xml-file via

```
doc = xmlReadFile(rem, NULL, 0);
```

it fails (doc == NULL) --> "I/O warning : failed to load HTTP resource"

**Question**:
Is there any additional property to set or other things, which can influence the behaviour of this funtion?

**Whole code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int main()
{
    const char *loc = "C:/Users/dirkn/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ConsoleApplication1/Debug/PHLI.xml";
    const char *rem = "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/PHLI.xml";
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    doc = xmlReadFile(loc, NULL, 0);
    //doc = xmlReadFile(rem, NULL, 0); 

    if (doc == NULL) {
        printf("error: could not parse file.");
    }
    else
    {
        root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

        if (root_element->name != NULL)
            printf(" %s\n", root_element->name);

        xmlFreeDoc(doc);    
    }

    /*
    * Cleanup function for the XML library.
    */
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Searching in source file, the message that you read "I/O warning : failed to load HTTP resource" appear when there is a return code >400 in one of the function called by "xmlReadFile". Have you tried to load a different XML file from a different page to check if the behaviour is the same?

Comment: Yes, I tried different xml files with the same result.
Unfortunately I use libxml2 only as a library so I can't debug into the source files for more information.
Hope there is someone out there who can try the example to verify the behavior or give a hint what to change.

Answer (score 0):

try to make a http GET request to load the file in buffer and safe it local.

```
xmlReadFile
```

is for local files

try to make an socket client what sending this request
and recv the response and safe it to read with xmlReadFile

```
get = build_get_query(host,page);
temp = send(sock2,get+sent,strlen(get)-sent,0);
temp = recv(sock2,buf,BUFSIZ,0);

char *build_get_query(char *host,char *page) {
char *query;
char *getpage = page;
char *tpl = "GET /%s HTTP\\1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nConnection: close:\r\n";


if(getpage[0] == '/'){
    getpage = getpage + 1;
}

query = (char *)malloc(strlen(getpage)+strlen(host)+strlen(USERAGENT)+strlen(tpl)-3);
sprintf(query,tpl,getpage,host,USERAGENT);
        
return query;}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).